# Add behavior to style setter

Tags: xamarin

i'm new Xamarin, can anyone suggest, how to add behaviors to the style of control in Xamarin xaml.
I have some ClickableImageBehavior and some imageBaseStyle, how to associate behavior with setter?

UPD

Details:
So... problem:

```
public class ClickableImageBehavior : Behavior<Image>
{
      // handle user tap on button.
}
```

And using looks like this:

```
<Image>
   <Image.Behaviors>
        <view:ClickableImageBehavior/>
   </Image.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

But i don't want to write this xaml on every button that has ClickableImageBehavior
I want to create some base style with this behavior and base properties and simple inherit it in every image like

```
<Image style="{StaticResource clickableImageStyle"/>
```

In WPF i can deal with it like in this [article](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/blend-behaviors-in-styles-dragpositionbehavior/), but how to do it in Xamarin xaml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert but when I added a behaviours it was always in a component like

```
<psc:EnumBindablePicker x:Name="enumpickerSpeechPart">
    <psc:EnumBindablePicker.Behaviors>
        <pscv:PickerBehavior x:Name="pickerBehaviorSpeechPart" />
    </psc:EnumBindablePicker.Behaviors>
</psc:EnumBindablePicker>
```

In the `ResourceDictionary` you can add calls to converters.

```
  <local:BooleanToObjectConverter x:Key="boolToStyleImage" x:TypeArguments="Style">
    <local:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{local:ImageResource Images.error.png}" />
      </Style>
    </local:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
    <local:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{local:ImageResource Images.success.png}" />
      </Style>
    </local:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
  </local:BooleanToObjectConverter>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it about my issue, i added some details int UPD